# Bootable Windows Iso and live Ubuntu Flavors on same Drive

Tags: flash, bootable-media

I want to put bootable windows 7 iso and all the Ubuntu flavors on same either large flash drive or a external drive. I also would like to be able to run these flavors as live instead of installing it. So this way I have one flash drive or external drive instead of a bunch of dvds and small flash drive. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: See if this helps>>>>https://www.linuxbabe.com/apps/create-multiboot-usb-linux-windows-iso

Comment: Will These create a live linux so I can run it and install it if it works? So basically have a windows iso and and have live linux flavors all in one disk?